# How to select the next row with two columns that jointly create a unique row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns with data (plus others) that look like:

```
id, revision, other cols
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
... (etc)
2, 1
2, 2
3, 3
... (etc)
```

While using a loop, how can I make sure that it gets the next row given these repeating values?

Consider a rough example:

```
declare @RowNum INT, @id INT, @revisionINT


select @id=MAX(id) FROM dim.staging 
select @RowNum = Count(*) FROM dim.staging
WHILE @RowNum > 0
BEGIN   
    select
    @id= id, @revision= revision

    -- do something here; print, insert, etc

    --------------------

    -- get next row

    select top 1 @id=id, @revision=revision from dim.staging where RevisionNumber > @RevisionNumber order by id -- gets me repeating values

    set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1                               --decrease count
END
```

This will not work as expected as it will start repeating values

```
select top 1 @id=id, @revision=revision from dim.staging where RevisionNumber > @RevisionNumber order by id
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a `WHILE` at all here? SQL is a set based language; it excel at set based solutions and performs awful at iterative ones. What are your expected results for your sample data as well; you forgot to include them

Comment: Very probably you can perform your desired action, ie an insert, using a single query; if you must loop then either insert your ID values into a temp table and pick off rows iteratively, or use a fast_forward cursor.